# Efficiently recalculating the gradient of a numpy array with unknown dimensionality

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have an N-dimensional numpy array `S`.  Every iteration, exactly one value in this array will change.

I have a second array, `G` that stores the gradient of `S`, as calculated by numpy's `gradient()` function.  Currently, my code unnecessarily recalculates all of `G` every time I update `S`, but this is unnecessary, as only one value in `S` has changed, and so I only should have to recalculate `1+d*2` values in `G`, where `d` is the number of dimensions in `S`.

This would be an easier problem to solve if I knew the dimensionality of the arrays, but the solutions I have come up with in the absence of this knowledge have been quite inefficient (not substantially better than just recalculating all of `G`).

Is there an efficient way to recalculate only the necessary values in `G`?

**Edit: adding my attempt, as requested**

The function returns a vector indicating the gradient of `S` at `coords` in each dimension.  It calculates this without calculating the gradient of `S` at every point, but the problem is that it does not seem to be very efficient.

It looks similar in some ways to the answers already posted, but maybe there is something quite inefficient about it?

The idea is the following: I iterate through each dimension, creating a slice that is a vector only in that dimension.  For each of these slices, I calculate the gradient and place the appropriate value from that gradient into the correct place in the returned vector `grad`.

The use of `min()` and `max()` is to deal with the boundary conditions.

```
    def getSGradAt(self,coords) :
        """Returns the gradient of S at position specified by
           the vector argument 'coords'.

           self.nDim : the number of dimensions of S
           self.nBins : the width of S (same in every dim)
           self.s : S  """
        grad = zeros(self.nDim)
        for d in xrange(self.nDim) :
            # create a slice through S that has size > 1 only in the current
            # dimension, d. 
            slices = list(coords)
            slices[d] = slice(max(0,coords[d]-1),min(self.nBins,coords[d]+2))
            # take the middle value from the gradient vector
            grad[d] = gradient(self.s[sl])[1] 
        return grad
```

The problem is that this doesn't run very quickly.  In fact, just taking the gradient of the whole array `S` seems to run faster (for `nBins = 25` and `nDim = 4`).

**Edited again, to add my final solution**

Here is what i ended up using.  This function updates `S`, changing the value at `X` by the amount `change`.  It then updates `G` using a variation on the technique proposed by Jaime.

```
    def changeSField(self,X,change) :
        # change s 
        self.s[X] += change

        # update g (gradient field)
        slices = tuple(slice(None if j-2 <= 0 else j-2, j+3, 1) for j in X)
        newGrads = gradient(self.s[slices])
        for i in arange(self.nDim) :
            self.g[i][slices] = newGrads[i]
```

Comment: `gradient` returns an array if the input is 1-dimensional and a list of arrays if the input has a number of dimensions other than 1. It looks like it wasn't meant to be used with arrays of runtime-determined dimension, and the list is going to exclude most of the clever slice-assignments you could do with an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is much to open for you to get a good answer: it is always a good idea to post your inefficient code, so that potential answerers can better help you. Anyway, lets say you know the coordinates of the point that has changed, and that you store those in a tuple named `coords`. First, lets construct a tuple of slices encompassing your point:

```
slices = tuple(slice(None if j-1 <= 0 else j-1, j+2, 1) for j in coords)
```

You may want to extend the limits to `j-2` and `j+3` so that the gradient is calculated using central differences whenever possible, but it will be slower.

You can now update you array doing something like:

```
G[slices] = np.gradient(N[slices])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This seems like the right direction to go.  To make it compatible with gradient (see the comment made by user2357112 above) the assignment required a little bit more than what you suggested. `for i in arange(len(g)) :
    g[i][slices] = s[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Uhmmm, I could work better if I had an example, but what about just creating a secondary array, S2 (by the way, I'd choose longer and more meaningful names for your variables) and recalculate the gradient for it, G2, and then introduce it back into G?

Another question is: if you don't know the dimensionality of S, how are you changing the particular element that changes? Are you just recalculating the whole of S?

I suggest you clarify this things so that people can help you better. 
Cheers!

Comment: I know the dimensionality of the array at run time, but not before then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't see how a secondary array S2 would help.  Can you clarify?  Thanks again.

Comment: Of course I can try and clarify. What you are uncomfortable with is to recalculate the gradient of the whole array, S. If you change S[ii,jj] (assuming two dimensions), the only values of the gradient that would change would be those whitin [ii-1:ii+2] and [jj-1:jj+2], i.e. a square 3x3 centered in [ii,jj]. All the rest are unaffected by the change, right? So, what I propose is to "cut" a slice of S around [ii,jj] so that we recalculate the gradient and then insert it into G. For that you would need a 5x5 square around [ii,jj] of which you would take the 3x3 you need.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  Yes, this is the approach that I was trying to take, but the challenge is that I don't know the dimensionality of the array until runtime.  The other response posted is similar to my first attempt, which I will now add to my question text above.